# SCROLL CURSOR to first search-result using an INDEX

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, cursor

**Problem:**
*I want to provide my users with an Excel-Grid-like Client-Side Application. That client accesses the PostgreSQL-Server over a Network-Connection.
The client offers a "Find"-Functionality. Instead of filtering and showing only the matching results, the "Find"-function just jumps to the first matching Row in the Grid. (Like the "Find"-Function in Excel)*

To reduce the bandwidth-usage and prevent lame LIMIT/OFFSET-Selects, I am using PostgreSQL with server-side cursors to allow scrolling over the sorted Table:

```
BEGIN WORK; 
DECLARE mCursor SCROLL CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY xyz
```

Scrolling and retrieval of the result-data is handled by calling Move/Fetch each time the client scrolls within the grid:

```
MOVE FORWARD/BACKWARD <offset> IN mCursor; FETCH 40 FROM mCursor;
```

Now i want to add the "Find"-Functionality witch uses an Index to find the first matching Result-Offset. The only way i know to integrate this functionality is to open a new connection and run the following query and then move the cursor to the returned rowNo:

```
SELECT t.rowNo 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC) AS rowNo 
    FROM table
) t 
WHERE t.ColumnName LIKE 'xyz%' 
LIMIT 1
```

Problem: This query is extremely slow because it can't use an index (2-3 Seconds for ~300k Rows).

Is there an other way to integrate this task more efficient?

Maybe by reading the offset directly from the index-data? Or by starting a query within the Cursor? Or is there a database-system allowing this functionality?

Comment: That is a server side cursor. It helps nothing for a querying client. Could you give a better explanation of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What is the client? If it is a fat one then you can keep state at the client and use a client side cursor not a server side one. If it is an HTML client then do it without a cursor.

Comment: Its a fat one (Java Application). But the cursor is not the problem. The Question is how to find the Offset-Position without counting all the rows before.

Comment: Have you already established that using LIMIT and OFFSET do not offer the required performance, and if so what the reason for that might be?

Comment: My measurements showed that an OFFSET >300k needs more than 4 seconds, which is way too long. (See: http://www.depesz.com/2011/05/20/pagination-with-fixed-order/)

Comment: And how much for the equivalent `move forward` cursor?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible to use an index only if the pattern started with a `%`.

I guess the problem is not that it can't use an index but that it has to scan the whole index to enumerate all table rows. Show the explain.

This will limit the index scan up to the searched pattern

```
SELECT min(t.rowNo)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC) AS rowNo, 
        ColumnName 
    FROM table
    where ColumnName <= 'xyz' || repeat('z', 100) -- Get all possible like 'xyz%'
) t 
WHERE t.ColumnName LIKE 'xyz%'
```